# Probability logic: how uncertain is the conclusion if the premises have the same uncertainty?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, predicate-logic

The question as given reads as follows: "If all of the uncertainties of the premises in the inferences below are equal, how small do these uncertainties have to be to guarantee that the conclusions of these inferences have probability at least .99?"

a) premises: {A,B} 
Conclusion: A IFF B

b) premises: {A, A implies B}
Conclusion: B

Apparently both answers are 0.05(from the back of the book) but I cannot figure out why. Anyone have any idea?

This from the book "probability logic" ernest adams. It is a question in section 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a typo in your post, but it seems to me that we can do better than $0.05$.

For example, here's (b). We are given that $P(B) \geq 0.99$ and $P(A^c) = P((A \ \text{implies} \ B)^c)$. I am assuming here that the "uncertainty" of $A$ is equal to $P(A^c)$. Also, I will assume that "implies" refers to the material conditional, i.e.
$$P(A \ \text{implies} \ B)=P(A^c \cup B),$$
so
$$P((A \ \text{implies} \ B)^c) = P(A \cap B^c).$$
Then, by our assumption that the premises have the same uncertainties, it follows that
$$P(A^c) = P(A \cap B^c) = P(B^c) - P(B^c \cap A^c) \leq 0.01 \leq 0.05$$
because $P(B) \geq 0.99$ implies $P(B^c) \leq 0.01$ and $P(B^c \cap A^c) \geq 0$.

I leave (a) to you.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your answer it is surprising however that the textbook solution is wrong...

Comment: It's not wrong, just not best.

Comment: I don't understand... the answer says that the upper bound of uncertainties is 0.05. Is this correct?

Comment: $0.05$ is _an_ upper bound, but it's not a very good one in view of the fact that $0.01$ is also an upper bound.

Comment: As in the premises have to have less uncertainty than 0.05... clearly if they have less than this it's fine...

Comment: Aha so you mean that there is a better upper bound... hm

Comment: Yes, I think the instructions to the exercise are poorly worded. "How small do these uncertainties have to be...?" Well, they certainly have to be bounded above by $1$, for example! Is that an acceptable answer?